# Convergence of solutions of the volterra integral equation with convergent kernels

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, integral-operators

Consider the following Volterra integral equation

$$
g(t) = \int_0^t K_n(t,s)w_n(s) ds
$$

where g(t) and K_n(t,s) are continuous and $K_n(t,s)\geq K_{n+1}(t,s)$ for all $t,s$. Moreover, $K_n(t,s)$ converges to $K(t,s)$.

The conditions of $K_n(t,s)$ are as follows :

1. $K_n(t,s)\neq 0 $ for each n and for all t,s.
2. $\frac{\partial K_n(t,s)}{\partial t}$ is continuous.
3. $K(t,s)\neq 0 $ for all t,s.

Conditions 1, 2 are sufficient to gurantee the existence of solution $w_n(s)$.

Then, can we say that the solution $w_n(s)$ also converges to some function $w(s)$?

If so, how can i prove it?

Comment: Please specify the exact conditions you are putting on your kernels in order to guarantee existence of unique solutions, otherwise I could just take $K_n$ converging monotonely to zero.

Comment: I have revised my question. Please see again.